# Setup alarm on SQS for messages automatically deleted after 14 days (retention period)

Tags: message, amazon-sqs, amazon-cloudwatch, alarm

The question is, the SQS message messages get deleted after a particular period of time that is 14 days max. I set up a cloud watch monitor for it which sends me a mail if there is a SQS message in the SQS queue, but what if I miss the mail and not check the message and it gets deleted. can i set up multiple remainders for one SQS queue message before it gets deleted?

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to create a CloudWatch alarm on the `ApproximateAgeOfOldestMessage` metric. The threshold should be set at a value slightly less than 14 days to ensure the old message isn't missed.

I'd like to note that in general if you are anticipating messages lingering in SQS for 14 days, this suggests you are not using SQS for its intended purpose. For a message to linger for 14 days suggests that whatever is processing the messages is severely deficient in its capacity. Once a message is seen and processed, you delete it from the queue, and in most cases the design is for this to happen within seconds or minutes, sometimes hours, but rarely multiple days.
`